# Integrating Apache Shiro on Play framework 2.1

Tags: apache, frameworks, playframework-2.1, shiro

I'm trying to integrate Apache Shiro into Play framework 2.1
I'm using an open source project (https://github.com/wsargent/play-shiro) that support play framework 2.0

I've tried to migrate this application from play 2.0 into 2.1 but I keep getting these errors when I compile the project...

Does anyone know how to handle this errors?

```
[play-shiro] $ compile
[info] Updating {file:/Users/shai/Documents/Projects/opensource/play-shiro/}play-shiro...
[info] Done updating.                                                        
[info] Compiling 13 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /Users/shai/Documents/Projects/opensource/play-shiro/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /Users/shai/Documents/Projects/opensource/play-shiro/app/views/login.scala.html:0: not found: type Flash
[error] /Users/shai/Documents/Projects/opensource/play-shiro/app/views/login.scala.html:1: not found: type Flash
[error] @(form: Form[(String,String)])(implicit flash: Flash)
[error]                                               ^
[error] /Users/shai/Documents/Projects/opensource/play-shiro/app/controllers/Login.scala:36: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.data.Form[(String, String)]
[error]  required: play.data.Form[(String, String)]
[error]     Ok(html.login(loginForm))
[error]                   ^
[error] /Users/shai/Documents/Projects/opensource/play-shiro/app/controllers/Login.scala:44: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.data.Form[(String, String)]
[error]  required: play.data.Form[(String, String)]
[error]       formWithErrors => { BadRequest(html.login(formWithErrors)) },
[error]                                                 ^
[error] /Users/shai/Documents/Projects/opensource/play-shiro/app/views/register.scala.html:0: not found: type Flash
[error] /Users/shai/Documents/Projects/opensource/play-shiro/app/views/register.scala.html:1: not found: type Flash
[error] @(form: Form[(String,String)])(implicit flash: Flash)
[error]                                               ^
[error] /Users/shai/Documents/Projects/opensource/play-shiro/app/controllers/Register.scala:30: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.data.Form[(String, String)]
[error]  required: play.data.Form[(String, String)]
[error]     Ok(html.register(registerForm))
[error]                      ^
[error] /Users/shai/Documents/Projects/opensource/play-shiro/app/controllers/Register.scala:37: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.data.Form[(String, String)]
[error]  required: play.data.Form[(String, String)]
[error]           BadRequest(html.login(formWithErrors))
[error]                                 ^
[error] /Users/shai/Documents/Projects/opensource/play-shiro/app/views/login.scala.html:19: value map is not a member of play.data.validation.ValidationError
[error]             @form.globalError.map { error =>
[error]                               ^
[error] /Users/shai/Documents/Projects/opensource/play-shiro/app/views/login.scala.html:53: not found: type Flash
[error] /Users/shai/Documents/Projects/opensource/play-shiro/app/views/login.scala.html:55: not found: type Flash
[error] /Users/shai/Documents/Projects/opensource/play-shiro/app/views/register.scala.html:18: value map is not a member of play.data.validation.ValidationError
[error]   @form.globalError.map { error =>
[error]                     ^
[error] /Users/shai/Documents/Projects/opensource/play-shiro/app/views/register.scala.html:51: not found: type Flash
[error] /Users/shai/Documents/Projects/opensource/play-shiro/app/views/register.scala.html:53: not found: type Flash
[error] 14 errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Apr 17, 2013 7:00:42 PM
[play-shiro] $
```

Answer (score 3):

I've upgraded the code to 2.1, but please, please consider using Play Authenticate or SecureSocial instead.  This code was never intended to be production quality.

Comment: I'm using your project as a basis of Play integration with Shiro (for production use, yes :) ) and want to thank you for open-sourcing it. I'll submit a pull request if there will be anything worth it.

Comment: Shiro is more suitable for our needs because it provides fine-grained role-based management and is framework-agnostic and that is good for our setting.

Comment: hey @WillSargent is your comment still valid? I'm considering using shiro and probably basing my work on yours, so I'm wondering if I should, or still fallback on other libs like SecureSocial (which might be overkill).
NVM... it's an RTFM one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

After the upgrade from Play! 2.0 to Play! 2.1, have you ran the following commands?

```
play clean
play clean-files
play compile
```

That's usually the cause of those compilation issues.

If the problem persists, have a look at the [migration guide](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Migration) to check if you actually followed all required steps.